# Dynamically draw a single polyline to current location

Tags: android, google-maps, google-polyline

In my android app, I want to create a single path/polyline from a specific location(far end) to my current location while moving. I could draw the polyline on map with now issue while when I moves to a new location another polyline is been drown on the map, so my map output is full of polylines whichh I don't need, I want only one polyline to be visible to my current location.

```
            PolylineOptions polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions().add(currentPosition).add(farEndPosition).width(10).color(Color.GREEN);
            Polyline polyline = googleMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove old Line before adding new one.

```
   Polyline  polyline ;

        public void addUpdatePolyLine()
            {
             PolylineOptions polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions().add(currentPosition).add(farEndPosition).width(10).color(Color.GREEN);
              if(polyline !=null)
              {
              polyline.remove();
                }
            polyline = googleMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions);
            }
```

Comment: It is working thx a lot my friend. I was trying to add the polyline first and then remove it during a handler loop every second,  that was my mistake.

Comment: But this will give a straight polyline from origin to destination,you should use legs to get  a proper polyline.